# Load XIB from separate app target

Tags: ios, swift, xib

In a separate target from my main app I've got a `xib` that I want to load.  I tried to do it like so, where `Feelings` is a class in the separate target:

```swift
class Feelings: UIView {
  public static func CreateView() -> Feelings {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "Feelings", bundle: bundle)
    let views = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)

    if let view = views[0] as? Feelings {
      return view
    }

    fatalError()
  }
}
```

The cast of view[0] to the `Feelings` class always fails though.  On the XIB file itself I clicked on the `File's Owner` and set it to be Feelings, and the Module properly showed the name of my extension target.

What step did I miss?

Comment: Is the view's class set to `Feelings` or just the file's owner?  You generally wouldn't set both and the class is the one you have to set to change the class of the view that comes out of the nib

Comment: That was it, thanks.  I blanked File's owner back out and set the class on the view.